# How to preserve LINQ table objects after merging?

Tags: linq, list, linq-to-sql

After merging 2 LINQ lists, how can I preserve the table objects and names? I thought that it would but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Here's how I created my lists:

```
var USquery = from uscomp in USdb.UScompanies             
          select new
          {
              uscomp.equity_cusip,
              uscomp.company_name,
              uscomp.ticker               
          }

var CAquery = from cacomp in CAdb.CAcompanies             
          select new
          {
              cacomp.equity_cusip,
              cacomp.company_name,
              cacomp.ticker               
          }
```

I merged the lists into:

```
var mergedList = USquery.Union(CAquery)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? The merging of the lists shouldn't change any of the items - what do you mean by "table objects" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're not "table objects", they're enumerators. To make them into actual lists, use ToList().